# Excel formula on cell for valid password

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, passwords

I'm creating a template for importing users in bulk to the system, one of the columns requires to input password,

I would like to create a condition on the [password] cell, in order to indicate to the person that input the details that the password is valid

those are the conditions:

```
Password must contain at least

6 characters

1 symbol

1 number

1 letter
```

This is what I tried : MEDIAN(6) AND (OR),EXACT(LOWER()))) but no luck.
all the symbols are valid but the values of the characters must be in English

is it possible?

Comment: What have you tried?  Anything?

Comment: This is the first time that I tried to do it so I google it and tried to combine some formulas but I can't make it work : this is what I try: MEDIAN(6) AND (OR),EXACT(LOWER())))

Comment: Why median()? What about len(A1)>=6 ? Have you considered data validation?

Comment: What for you is a valid symbol? Also, include your attempt into the question (with some explaination what you expected it would do)

Comment: I tried data validation but I need that the cell validation to be more complex with the condition I munched in the question above

Comment: @JvdV for example : asdf!1 , AAAA$2, ,asdlkj#$112 but not !21s,sssssss etc

Comment: Or perhaps you should make yourself a list of symbols or even characters that are not valid - what about greek?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A password-validator immediately screamed 'regular-expressions'. Will you want to go down the path of VBA, you'd require the following pattern:

```
^(?=.*?[!#$])(?=.*?[A-Za-z])(?=.*?\d).{6,}$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xn4I2i/1)

---

To mimic this in relative easy native functionality you could go with xpath-expressions:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&LOWER(A1)&"</s></t>","//s[translate(.,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','')!=.][translate(.,'0123456789','')!=.][translate(.,'!#$','')!=.][string-length()>=6]")))
```

- `translate(.,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','')!=.]` would mimic the positive lookahead for any letter;
- `[translate(.,'0123456789','')!=.]` would mimic the positive lookahead for any number;
- `[translate(.,'!#$','')!=.]` would mimic the positive lookahead for any symbol (as given in the character class);
- `[string-length()>=6]` would mimic the 6+ characters needed for valid input.

Comment: Agree with this, perhaps my use of data validation is useful for evaluating the logic steps.

Comment: so if I change only to F it will work for all the cells in F?

Comment: Yooo, Thank you very much for your time and the answer it works!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have done this in the few minutes between posting the comment and this answer, you can expand it to include whatever other conditions you want:

[image]

```
and(len(A1)>=6,MAX(IFERROR(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1,1),"")))
```

is the formula used in the data validation. Youi can see that A1 meets the length >=6 but I have not controlled that the count of numbers, hiowever you can add that.